# Abruptly stop executing a command and continue to the next one

Tags: r

I have a set of files on which I need to apply `rpart` algorithm. Some of these files takes too long for computation. How can I skip such cases (eg. cases that take more than an hour) and continue on to the next one?

```
for (i in num)
{
print(i)
infilename  = filenames[i]
tmpData = read.table(infilename, header = TRUE,  sep= "\t")
retval = rpart(fmla[i],  dat=tmpData, method = "class")
print (retval)
}
```

Edit:
Based on suggestin from @Dwin, I am doing the following but it does not work. Where I am doing wrong?

```
for (i in num)
{
print(i)
infilename  = filenames[i]
tmpData = read.table(infilename, header = TRUE,  sep= "\t")
retVal= NULL
setTimeLimit(cpu=10)
retval = try(rpart(fmla,  dat=tmpData, method = "class") )
print (retval)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just using regular R functions (and not coding this from scratch), you will need to come up with some way to estimate the conditions leading to excessive times. This might be a test that looks at the dimensions of a dataframe and skips the next `rpart` computation if the product of `dim(dfrm)` exceeds a certain threshold.

```
retval = if(prod(dim(tmpData)) < 1e6) {
                rpart(fmla[i],  dat=tmpData, method = "class") }
```

Notice that at the moment you are overwriting `retval` with every loop iteration rather than storing it to a durable object.

You could also try using the functions `setTimeLimit` and `setSessionLimit` but these will throw an error condition and you may need to put your code inside a `try` function  to recover gracefully:

```
 setTimeLimit(cpu=2)
for (i in 4:8) {x <- 1:10^i;x=x^3}
 max(x)
#[1] 1e+24
# did not exceed the limits
x^(1/3)
#[1]     1     2     3     4     5     6     7Error: reached CPU time limit
```

Comment: Thanks @DWin, setTimeLimit seems reasonable. I am waiting for if someone else is having any idea.

Comment: thanks but the actual code does not work. Your example works though.