# How to terminate an ongoing processing abruptly

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call a python function using subprocess call. I have seen many examples of subprocess but didn't see any that call another python function. I am not sure if it can be done or not.

My function `fakeFxn` do some processing that may take time as little as few seconds or as long as couple of hours. I want to skip those that takes more than a particular time, say 1 hour. This function is also returning me some value that I need to collect.

```
def fakeFxn(val):
    if (val== "terminate"):
        for i in range(10):
            z = "t"
        return(z)
    else:
        for i in range(100000000): #Instead of infinite loop, here I am doing some big computation
            y = "nt"
        return(y)


import subprocess
elapsedTime = 0
p = subprocess.Popen(retval = fakeFxn("terminate"))
rc = p.poll()  #returncode
while (rc == None):
    sleep(5)
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 5
    if(elapsedTime <10):
        rc = p.poll()
        continue
    else:
        rc = "timeout"
        p.kill()
        break
```

Is this a good way to do it? Or is there any alternate way to do the same? I asked a related question here: [Abruptly stop executing a command and continue to the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976571/abruptly-stop-executing-a-command-and-continue-to-the-next-one)

My actual function is the ``rpart` function of this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about through `subprocess`, but you should be able to do this with the help of `multiprocessing` and a wrapper function:

```
import time
from Queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def fakeFxn(val):
    if val == 'terminate':
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return 't'
    else:
        time.sleep(1000)
        return 'nt'

def ffWrapper(val, queue):
    retval = fakeFxn(val)
    queue.put(retval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=ffWrapper, args=('terminate', q))
    p.start()
    rc = ''
    try:
        rc = q.get(timeout=10)
    except Empty:
        print 'timeout'
    p.terminate()
    print rc
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` should be used for executing external programs, not Python functions in one's module.

For your particular task you're better off using [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) modules. Your code *could* be rewritten like this (times out after two seconds):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


def fake_function(arg):
    time.sleep(arg)
    print arg 


p = Process(target=fake_function, args=(10,))
p.start()
p.join(timeout=2)
p.terminate()
```

Comment: How can I recieve the returned value from the fake_fuction assuming it returns something.

Comment: @learner You could put a wrapper function around fake_function that accepts the arguments for fake_function and a Queue. In the wrapper, you could then put the return value of fake_function into the Queue, and then get that value again at a higher level.

Comment: @learner Or, use `multiprocessing.Pool` for that, which is best suited for processing a data set in parallel and fetching the results.